# Server accessible via SSH and HTTP on all machines except one client

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, virtualhost

**Edit 3:**

Weird discovery.  This problem is only happening from one specific client.  All three sites are accessible via domain name from any computer except my primary desktop.  This desktop can only access the server (for HTTP or for SSH) via the local IP address 192.168.0.X not via the external IP or the domain name(s).  From all other machines, everything works as expected.

I checked my fail2ban logs and firewall to make sure this specific machine wasn't getting blocked.  What else could the problem be?  It's a huge pain to not be able to access my server from my primary desktop.

Both are hard-wired to the same router via ethernet cables, if that matters.

---

**Original Post:**

I have three virtual hosts defined in Apache (all three with .conf files stored in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` that have been enabled via `a2ensite`).

Prior to updating from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04, all three worked fine.  After updating, none of them would load in the browser, so I did a lot of troubleshooting.  Here is what I have done/double-checked so far:

- Reinstalled apache2 and php
- Checked `apache2.conf`, including running `apache2ctl -t` to debug - there are no errors.
- Checked conf files for each site, ran `apache2ctl -S` to ensure all were recognized.  Each one specifies the ServerName (domain name) and DocumentRoot (local directory).  These values have been triple checked for correctness.
- Checked DNS settings.  All three domain names do point to the correct IP address (used `dig` to confirm).
- Checked firewall settings - port 80 is open and Apache is listening on it.

When accessing any of the three sites by domain name, the browser gives the error message: "This site can't be reached. domain.com took too long to respond."

I can access the default site (the first one loaded by Apache) with no problem if I type the IP address in the browser instead of the domain name.

I feel like this is some sort of Apache configuration I'm messing up somehow but all I have is the default `apache2.conf` file from fresh installation along with the virtual host conf files, which all have the following format:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName somedomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/foldername"
    <Directory /var/www/foldername>
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride XXXXXXXXXX
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The AllowOverride is `None` for one site and `Fileinfo Options` for the other two.

Any idea what I'm missing?

---

**Edit 1:** Adding output from `dig`, `ping`, and `curl`

```
angela@pop-os:~$ dig mydomain.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P1-1ubuntu2.5-Ubuntu <<>> mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 65412
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mydomain.com.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com.       1799    IN  A   MY_SERVER_IP

;; Query time: 60 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Sat Aug 31 23:54:55 EDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 57

angela@pop-os:~$ ping mydomain.com
PING mydomain.com (MY_SERVER_IP) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- mydomain.com ping statistics ---
18 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 415ms

angela@pop-os:~$ curl -v mydomain.com
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
*   Trying MY_SERVER_IP...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x558ffb3d7880)
```

---

**Edit 2:** Adding output for `curl ip_address` and also for netstat.

```
angela@pop-os:~$ curl -v MY_SERVER_IP
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x5601183bb880)
*   Trying MY_SERVER_IP...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x5601183bb880)
* connect to MY_SERVER_IP port 80 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to MY_SERVER_IP port 80: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to MY_SERVER_IP port 80: Connection timed out
```

```
user@server:~$ sudo netstat -anp | grep apache
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      28228/apache2
```

Comment: The error you are giving sounds more indicative of a DNS or domain resolution issue. Can you show that the domain is resolving correctly maybe using `ping` and `curl -v your domain.com` to prove the issue might be elsewhere?

Comment: Added output from dig, ping, and curl to the original post - all three appear to be finding the correct IP address (identified by `MY_SERVER_IP` in the output above).

Comment: The curl output looks strange to me... can you also curl.just the IP address to see that it returns the HTTP headers of the default vhost? The current curl output doesn't seem to output any headers which is concerning. But definitely looks like maybe it is Apache not listening on the domain vhost correctly.

Comment: Ah, the extra "expire in" curl stuff may actually be some debug stuff that slipped in a release: https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2019-02/0013.html

Comment: Added the curl output you suggested to original post; also added netstat output from the server.

Comment: Have you confirmed that Apache process is the correct one and not some hanging around from the upgrade? I'm wondering if there is a zombie Apache process hanging on to Port 80 that isn't responding. Curl is failing to connect to the Port but netstat does indeed show a process listening. I would next try forcefully killing that process and making sure there is a new process listening when Apache is started.

Comment: I have restarted the server throughout this troubleshooting process, so I doubt it was a zombie Apache. :)  But I did just kill the existing apache process, restarted apache, then double checked that the new apache process was listening on port 80 (output is same as above, but with new pid).  curl still times out & browser still cannot connect to domain name.

Comment: OK. Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure what might be going on here. I can only offer some other suggestions such as working backwards to a default Apache config to try and eliminate any user changes. If it still doesn't work then it is more likely a network issue. Try to run the same curl commands on the server itself against 127.0.0.1. If working there then it might next make sense to run a `tcpdump` during some requests and load the dump into Wireshark to try and determine what is happening non the wire and if the requests even get to the server.

Comment: Okay thanks for trying to help!  I'll work on those suggestions and update the post if any new info comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the "right" solution, but it worked for me.  In the end, all I did was add a line to `/etc/hosts` on the "broken" client that could not connect to the server.  I put the internal IP address (which I have my router set up to keep the same for all of my main devices, including my server) followed by a space separated list of the domains hosted on that server.  Example:

```
192.168.0.1     domain1.com domain2.com domain3.com sub.domain3.com
```

This doesn't seem like a good, dynamic, permanent fix.  But it solves the problem for now.